# MonadRandom: why stack overflow happens?

Tags: haskell, random, stack-overflow, monads

This question is certainly for stackoverflow.com

here is the sample

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Random
import Control.Exception

data Tdata = Tdata Int Int Integer String

randomTdata :: (Monad m, RandomGen g) => RandT g m Tdata
randomTdata = do
  a <- getRandom
  b <- getRandom
  c <- getRandom
  return $ Tdata a b c "random"


manyTdata :: IO [Tdata]
manyTdata = do
  g <- newStdGen
  evalRandT (sequence $ repeat randomTdata) g

main = do
  a <- manyTdata
  b <- evaluate $ take 1 a
  return ()
```

after compilation this return

```
Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.
Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it
```

How can it happen ? Is MonadRandom not lazy or what else ? And how to define the cause of stack overflow in cases like that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue arises because you are building `IO` into your `manyTdata` function.
The monad transformer ends up being of type `RandT g IO Tdata`. Because each element of
your infinite list can consist of `IO` actions, the entirety of the infinite list
returned by `manyTdata` must be evaluated *completely* before the function can return
any results.

The simplest solution would be to use `Rand` instead of `RandT`, as using the tranformer
isn't really useful here, anyway; you could also change the base monad to something like
the `Identity` monad by changing `manyTdata` to

```
manyTdata :: IO [Tdata]
manyTdata = do
  g <- newStdGen
  return $ runIdentity $ evalRandT (sequence $ repeat randomTdata) g
```

Which will terminate in a finite amount of time. The error concerning your stack size
is simply a result of recursively expanding your list of `IO` actions. Your code says to sequence all of these actions, so they all have to be performed, it has nothing to do with laziness.

Something else to think about, rather than using `randomTdata`, consider
making `Tdata` an instance of the `Random` class.